# Launchpad SSO should transition to login.ubuntu.com

Tags: feature-request, openid

Posting on behalf of our infrastructure folks,

The launchpad team would like to consolidate their single sign on in favor of a SSO for all Ubuntu users, [login.ubuntu.com](http://login.ubuntu.com), which is what all the newer Ubuntu services are using since it's branded nicer and easier to use.

(This is a wishlist request, the lp service isn't going away any time soon.)