# Login in option for launchpad no longer autoexpands, confusing

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I don't remember when this changed but before when you clicked "log in with launchpad" the little options thing would autoexpand and let you put your username in a field so that you can use it to log in.

Now when you click on the lp button nothing happens, and it's non obvious that you need to next click on "More OpenID options" to expand the thing to add in your username.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The next build will fix this.

An oversight on my part.  None of our default* top-level providers require entering a name so I assumed the "More" div would always be expanded, my apologies.

<sub>*OpenID.SE, Google, Yahoo, MyOpenID, and Facebook</sub>

Comment: Ah, I think login.ubuntu.com doesn't have this requirement: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1159/launchpad-sso-should-transition-to-login-ubuntu-com

Comment: (Feel free to contact me via mail if you need me to connect you to an SSO person @ Canonical.

Comment: So, should this be fixed yet? I seem to still be having this problem: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1545/unable-to-login-using-launchpad-openid-text-input-box-fails-to-appear