# Unable to login using launchpad openID, text input box fails to appear.

Tags: support, status-completed, login

Should be in META, but I can't post there without logging in:I am unable to login using the Launchpad OpenID. When I click the launchpad button the page stays the same. (It has links to recover my account or make a new one, but no input boxes.) This has worked for me before with firefox4. It also does not work with Chromium. I'm not sure what has changed. What can I do to login? I'm using firefox 4. I don't have the noscript plugin installed.

Comment: To help narrow the cause of the login issue, has the Launchpad OpenID ever worked for you while using Firefox 4?  Have you tried another web browser (e.g., Chromium)?

Comment: @Kory I have updated my question to address the questions you asked.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1452/login-in-option-for-launchpad-no-longer-autoexpands-confusing)

Comment: @Marco Ceppi Yes, it sounds the same, but it has the status-completed tag. Does that mean it should be fixed but it's not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I finally got in to my account:
Clear the cache and cookies in your browser. Then go to the login page and click the more OpenID options link. Put in `https://launchpad.net/~<your-launchpad-user-name>` and click sign in.

Comment: Also remember, when you clear your cache and cookies, to specify the correct "Time range to clear:".