# LaunchPad Single Sign On needs to be replaced with Ubuntu SSO

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, login

Related to this [request](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1159/launchpad-sso-should-transition-to-login-ubuntu-com) only with an update in urgency and focus in completion.

Ubuntu SSO is the universally recognized login provider for the Ubuntu community, as such Ask Ubuntu needs to use it over Launchpad. During one of the sessions at UDS-P it was confirmed that Ask Ubuntu should be changed to use Ubuntu SSO instead `https://login.ubuntu.com/`

Comment: Can't we have both? (I mean for the time being, until Launchpad SSO is phased out.)

Answer (score 3):

I went and took a whack at this and encountered two problems.

- The presented credentials from SSO don't match those from Launchpad
- There's only space for one custom login provider.

There are a few thousand people using launchpad at the moment, so I can't really justify pulling it in favor of Ubuntu SSO.

Comment: I appreciate you looking in to this, couldn't you add a smaller LP icon in the "Other options" panel? Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcoCeppi eh... moving the LP icon is going to confuse lots of people, especially since we don't show those smaller icons by default.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check back if this is okay. I just know that the LaunchPad login is eventually going to be phased out in favor of Ubuntu SSO. To my knowledge they share the same login database, they just report different Claimed IDs

Answer (score 2):

Is this problem now solved as the login procedure [re-branded](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/web-service-changes-to-ubuntu-accounts) ?

I think you should change the Icon...

[image]

...and the redirection screen.

[image]

Comment: The problem isn't in the form but the base: *"The presented credentials from SSO don't match those from Launchpad"*