# I have a UbuntuOne account, why can't I use it to login here?

Tags: discussion, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving to Ubuntu Single Sign On](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2837/moving-to-ubuntu-single-sign-on)

That pretty much sums it up.

I've tried.  Failed.  Did I miss it?  Feel free to call me out if I did.  I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu One uses the [Ubuntu Single Sign On](https://login.ubuntu.com/) service, which acts as an [OpenID](http://openid.net/) Provider.

Stack Exchange supports OpenID login, so you can add this identity to your account:

1. Go to your profile page and click the `my logins` link near the top.
2. In the window that opens, pick `add more logins...`
3. On this page, enter `https://login.ubuntu.com` into the field for your OpenID (and clear the Launchpad username field if it contains anything).
4. Click `Log In`, and you should be presented with the same pages you see when logging in to the Ubuntu One site, for instance.

Once this is complete, you should be able to log in to your account on this site by using `https://login.ubuntu.com` as the OpenID URL.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: I find it amusing that this is the most highly voted response, since it doesn't answer the question I asked.  I could have figured out how to log in with an OpenID login, if I had one.  I **have** a UbuntuOne account, and as explained [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3061/61514), it wasn't among the ways listed on [this site](http://askubuntu.com/users/login).  So, I thought that was bad form, and I typed my question (or some near variant of it) into the search bar, and ended up here. What got me to logging into UbuntuOne was trying to search for a bug with SoundJuicer & Ubuntu 12.04 [EOM]

Comment: You asked why you couldn't use your Ubuntu One account to log in to this site.  I explained how you could do so (well, I explained how to use Ubuntu SSO: Ubuntu One doesn't actually manage your credentials).

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not among the list of recommended ways of signing into Askubuntu.com. The ones I know which are listed are, the Askubuntu, Stackoverflow, social networks and mail providers logins.

However, you are free to contact them through the 'Contact Us' or check the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) if your question is among answered ones.

Comment: A request has already been made and is in progress.

Answer (score -5):

AskUbuntu is a community based site developed and maintained by volunteers. It has emerged from Area 51 ( http://area51.stackexchange.com/ ) and is not (and can not be) linked directly with any enterprise (see: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq ). 
Ubuntu One is a service from Canonical, the enterprise behind Ubuntu.

Comment: -1, as James explained in his answer, it is possible. That and it is linked to Canonical, because Stackexchange needed to obtain permission to in order to use the official branding.